# Import React Material UI Icons dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, icons

The main idea is to only import react material UI icons when it is needed or rather when dynamically where we wouldn't know the icon name at compile time. (Let's gurentee that we would have valid icon names).

My approach was to use a require statment with dynamic path:

```
const IconComponent = require(`@material-ui/icons/${icon}`).default;
```

This works fine but some warnings are showing up.

> ./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/utils/createSvgIcon.d.ts 3:8
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:8)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> | import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
> |
> declare function createSvgIcon(path: React.ReactNode, displayName: string): typeof SvgIcon;
> |
> | export default createSvgIcon;

./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/index.d.ts 4:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
|

> type SvgIconComponent = typeof SvgIcon;
> |
> | export const AccessAlarm: SvgIconComponent;

My question is: How could we avoid these warnings and do the dynamic import in the appropriate way ?

Comment: please provide a snippet with a reproducible situation so we can use it as a starting point.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of another question, where I've posted an answer that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332935

Answer (score 3):

You can create a **hook** for this. like the following.

```
//1) $ npm i string-similarity
```

```
import * as icons from '@material-ui/icons'
import stringSimilarity from 'string-similarity'

function useIcons(word) {
  const iconsNames = Object.keys(icons)

  var matches = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(word, iconsNames)
  const bestMathch = matches.bestMatch.target
  const Icon = icons[bestMathch]
  return Icon
}
export default useIcons
```

```
import Icon from './myCustomeHooks/useIcons'
// other file like
const Icon =  useIcons('tablechart')  // not the name should start with capital letter in case you use reactjs


// now you can use the icon as you like
<Icon/>
```

---

**please note**: `import * as icons from '@material-ui/icons'` is the same as `const * as icons = require('@material-ui/icons').default;`

---

#### [option 2](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#font-awesome)

```
import React from 'react';
import { loadCSS } from 'fg-loadcss';
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { green } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      '& > .fa': {
        margin: theme.spacing(2),
      },
    },
  }),
);

export default function FontAwesome() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const node = loadCSS(
      'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css',
      document.querySelector('#font-awesome-css'),
    );

    return () => {
      node.parentNode!.removeChild(node);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" />
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" color="primary" />
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" color="secondary" />
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" style={{ color: green[500] }} />
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" fontSize="small" />
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer will import whole icon in Icon component, that's not @SoS 777 want.

Answer (score 0):

first is

```
(async () => {
  if (somethingIsTrue) {
    const { default: myDefault, foo, bar } = await 
import('/modules/my-module.js');
  }
})();
```

second method is

```
let module = await import('/modules/my-module.js');
```

nice working example you can tweak is

```
const main = document.querySelector("main");
for (const link of document.querySelectorAll("nav > a")) {
 link.addEventListener("click", e => {
 e.preventDefault();

 import('/modules/my-module.js')
   .then(module => {
     module.loadPageInto(main);
   })
    .catch(err => {
     main.textContent = err.message;
    });
 }
```

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point. The module's name that I am trying to import is dynamic. I can't tell the module at compile time. It is decided at run time. The trick is how to achieve this behaviour without raising errors or warnings because I got it to work but can't get rid of that warning.
Please correct me if I am missing something.