# Is there a way to dynamic/lazy import material ui icons without importing all the icons module?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I found this post, but it's not been answered..
[Import React Material UI Icons dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65249396/import-react-material-ui-icons-dynamically)

Currently, I have the code below, and it works, but I don't want to use

> import * as Icons from '@mui/icons-material';

```
import { createElement } from 'react';
import * as Icons from '@mui/icons-material';

export const MaterialUIIcon = ({ iconName }) => {
    return createElement(Icons[iconName]});
};
```

Is there a way to import an icon from a string without importing all other unrelated icons?
Something like `React.lazy(() => import('@mui/icons-material/${iconName}'));` which I tried but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not a perfect solution, it may go some way towards what you want to accomplish. As far as I can tell, you need to explicitly import every icon you wish to use so that these will be within your build files. Importing the entire icon library would result in much larger build files than is necessary.

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
// default icon
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";

const getIcon = (icon: string) => {
  // add as many icons as you need
  switch (icon) {
    case "Add":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Add"));
    case "Remove":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Remove"));
    case "Percent":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Percent"));
    case "Calculate":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Calculate"));
    case "Functions":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Functions"));
    case "Cloud":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Cloud"));
    case "Bluetooth":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Bluetooth"));
    case "Lock":
      return lazy(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Lock"));
    default:
      return CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon;
  }
};

export interface DynamicIconProps {
  icon: string;
}

const DynamicIcon = ({ icon }: DynamicIconProps) => {
  const SelectedIcon = getIcon(icon);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon />}>
      <SelectedIcon />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default DynamicIcon;
```